# Get all child attributes using parent id jquery

Tags: jquery, html

how do i get all child attributes by parent id and return an array of object example

I want a result like this:

```
pat_101 = adm_01-adm01, adm_01-adm02, adm_01-adm03
pat_102 = adm_04-adm04, adm_05-adm05, adm_06-adm06
pat_103 = adm_07-adm07, adm_08-adm08, adm_09-adm09
```

From this html:

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li id="pat_101">
       <ul>
         <li id ="adm_01" title="adm101"></li>
         <li id ="adm_02" title="adm102"></li>
         <li id ="adm_03" title="adm103"></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="pat_102">
       <ul>
         <li id ="adm_04" title="adm104"></li>
         <li id ="adm_05" title="adm105"></li>
         <li id ="adm_06" title="adm106"></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="pat_103">
       <ul>
         <li id ="adm_07" title="adm107"></li>
         <li id ="adm_08" title="adm108"></li>
         <li id ="adm_09" title="adm109"></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>    
<div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Good Assignment you given for us

Comment: That's very tough, i can't do it....^^

Comment: @coder Please understand! Sorry for that comment we didn't have time to write all the code for you. First you have try and show the code to us what you have tried and we will suggest or modified to get the answer for you.

Comment: google "jquery children" and you'll find the answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

So here's an answer, to welcome you to stackoverflow.com:

```
var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
var output = ""
var children
for (var ii=0, parent; parent=parents[ii]; ii++) {
  children = parent.getElementsByTagName("li")
  if (children.length) {
    childArray = []
    for (var jj=0, child; child=children[jj]; jj++) {
      childArray[jj] = child.id
    }
    output += parent.id + " = " + childArray.join(", ") + "\n"
  }
}

output = output.slice(0, -1)
console.log (output);
```

Perhaps you'd like to work through this, line by line, looking up the keywords on Google and making sure you understand them. When you're ready, you can close this window and rewrite the method for yourself, just using your notes, without looking at the original. Happy Karma!